# Python3.7 thread using 100% CPU and causing process to hang. How to avoid it?

Tags: python, regex, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I'm running a Python script that is spawning threads in which it's analyzing text with complicated regex patterns using the re module. In some situations when the input string is very long, the Python interpreter takes up to 100% of CPU of my t2.micro EC2 machine (1 vCPU, 1 GB of RAM) and the script stops working (probably because of the lack of resources).

I was trying to find a way to kill a thread after some timeout - but in my case it's not possible to check any flag in the loop, since the thread never exits the regex function. Also it is crucial to not to kill the whole process - ideally the application should be running 24/7.

Maybe it is possible to somehow monitor the resources that are taken by the thread and raise some kind of exception after specified threshold?

The very, very simplified example of my script is this code:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import re

pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers)


def check_difficult_regex(pattern, string):
    # time-consuming operations in here

pool.submit(check_difficult_regex, pattern, text)
```

Comment: Without a [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code example, it's difficult to know exactly what you're asking for here. Can you create a basic example that reproduces your problem?

Comment: If the culprit is regex, the reason lies in catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: Kindly show some form of example as per your scenario to see how best to help you, depending on how you have structured your code and what paradigms you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, however my question is not about how to optimalize a regex pattern - it's  about how to kill or stop a timeouted (hanged) python thread without affecting the process.